# Did i break my new toy? :-(

Tags: boot-issues

So recently i bought a RPi3 and made a custom case for it. Messed around with retropie and all seamed fine. The Problem is i took it to a friends house and somebody plugged it into a HDMI output (not imput) but once i got it home hdmi shows no signal when i plug it to my tv.I tried formating the SD card with no success. Tried also changing config file to boost hdmi. Nothing.
After that i tried plugging everything (same SD card, same TV, same HDMI cable, power supply) into another RPi3 i have and it works just fine. Tried to connect to the faulty PI via WINSCP and no answer.
I tried every possible solution i could find in the internet (loose SD card, all recommended config file tweaks etc).
Red LED lights just fine. The green one blinks a little and freezes for a while then turns off.
I am really clueless and dont want to discard my pi because it was expensive (it may not be expensive in many places but in my country it is).

Please have in mind i am a newbie to PI and electronics (not my field of studies) but i am trying to learn what i can.

If anybody can help me if not to make it work at least to understand what might have happened i would appreciate it a lot.

Cheers guys.

Comment: Have you tried using a different SD card? And or power supply?

Comment: Yes I did. Besides my other Pi works fine with this same SD card and power supply. Could it be that my buddy turned its hdmi into a laptop output? I really dont know what else could it be. I did a lot to stuff to the poor RPi but it was working fine. As soon as that happened it went dead. I am just worried i did something else that can also kill my other PI. I put it in a case i made myself with USB extension cords, hdmi extension and power button. All working good with the other one. Sorry but i am pretty dumb at this (learning a lot since i started this though).

Comment: I'm a wee bit confused as to the state of the Pi - you say you tried to change the config file to boost HDMI (which would require that the Pi's on and communicating over SSH), but you go on to say that it's not responding/dead/etc. Can you confirm whether the Pi's accessable over SSH?

Comment: Hi goobering thank you for your comment. I am not too familiar with SSH (i am a lawyer with no background in electronics). All i know is that i tried to connect to it via WINSCP and my pc found nothing. I was dumb enough to format my SD card before doing that. Then i configured wifi using my other pi. Then took the SD card out and put it into the faulty RPi. Tried to connect but the connection timed out. I changed the config file by sticking the SD card to my PC and the wrote the lines using NOTEPAD++. Again. Sorry if i am not very clear. I am pretty dumb at this.

Comment: if the SDcard boots in one PI3 and you can see on the monitor, and not the other, you've got some "electrical" problems with the other pi for sure - does the red power light come on? does the green activity light near it flicker at all? does it flash a particular number of times rather than flicker?